# Flutter, How can set height TextFromFiled with Container (counter text)?

Tags: flutter

I want to set height TextFormFeild with Container
There are some bottom padding? between Container and TextFormField
So focusedBorder can't cover all Container edge.
There are no paddings in parent Container.
How can I solve it.

[TextFormField With Container Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAdER.png)

This is my code

````
                    height: 130,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 40.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: const Color(0xffDDDDDD),
                          width: 0.5,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
                            offset: Offset(0, 1),
                            blurRadius: 2,
                          )
                        ]),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      maxLength: 200,
                      buildCounter: (context,
                          {required currentLength,
                          required isFocused,
                          maxLength}) {
                        return Container(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -35, 0),
                          child: Text("$currentLength / $maxLength"),
                        );
                      },
                      maxLines: 5,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  width: 2, color: Color(0xffFa7E66))),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 0.0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'hint text',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0, color: Color(0xff444444))),
                    ),
                  ),```
````

Comment: This question requires more code of the surrounded widgets.

Comment: I kind of found what's causing this issue: the character limit text (`0/200`). Try to remove `maxLength` and `buildCounter` to see that it's true. Not sure how to solve this though, hope you will be able to do it on your own.